# unable to indent / shift right multiple lines of text in textedit

Tags: macos, shortcut, text-editor, textedit

New to mac and am not able to highlight and indent multiple lines of text using textedit.

I see many solutions that seem to only apply to older version of OSX / text edit.

Command + ] is functionless in text edit.

Comment: Not sure that is an option anymore, you may have to go elsewhere as Apple, in their infinite wisdom, have decided to remove that feature. Only a cynic would add "to make certain app developers happy." I am not such a person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think this feature or function is coming back to TextEdit on 10.14 so I’d look to another editor if you need this super useful feature.

I’m a big fan of `vi` or more technically correct `vim` in the terminal since it’s free and included with each and every Mac *(and because my initial learning curve for that peculiar editor is behind me)*. If you want a more graphical and super powerful free text editor - go get BBEdit which allows free usage of the core editing functions after the free trial of the licensed portion expires:

- http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit

You’ll spend a little time getting either of these set up, but if you indent regularly - text edit isn’t worth all the time you’ll waste on it without more powerful features. I think the new Xcode beta has this feature from watching the 2018 WWDC videos, but I don’t think that’s released to non-paid developers quite yet.

Also, I would recommend spending a good amount of time learning the bookmark functionality on macOS in terminal app to get the full benefit (or choose and use `tmux` / `screen` / docker) to extend and run linux as needed if the Apple tools aren't making you feel super productive to edit and work from the command line (like the command `open .` to open a finder window from the current working directory).

- https://pragprog.com/book/bhtmux2/tmux-2
- https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/keyboard-shortcuts-trmlshtcts/mac

Comment: brand new to OSX, but not brand new it unix! did not know VIM came standard.

ill make them move over to that.

Comment: @ewagness OK - then I'll edit a couple more resources. Terminal bookmarks either are the best thing ever or people won't use them. Glad that will work for this case - super powerful editor even though many of the command shortcuts have an EMACS heritage... (***ducks and covers***)

Comment: Or `vim`'s arch nemesis `nano`